# Lorentz force expression

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

As expression of [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) is given by 
$F=q B v\sin\theta$. Now my doubt is why we cannot took $v \cos\theta$ in the expression and what about the direction of magnetic field?

Comment: So you think Lorentz mistook a sine for a cosine?

Comment: @my2cts Your comment really made me laugh. I'm really grateful to you. (Please don't consider this as an ironical statement, I'm really thankful to you, I was feeling low and your comment has helped me a lot)

Comment: @Knight You really made my day , that is very kind.

Answer (score 2):

The definition you have given for the Lorentz force is not the most general one. Given a magnetic field $B$ and a particle with charge $q$ that moves with velocity $v$, the Lorentz force is given by  $$F_L=q v\times B\; , $$ where $\times$ stands for the vectorial product. So, if the angle between the vectors $B$ and $v$ is $\theta$ the Lorentz force becomes $$ |F_L|= q|v| |B|\sin\theta\; ,$$ as you have written. In addition, if you apply an electric field $E$, the Lorentz force turns into $$ F_L=q(E+v\times B)\; .$$

Comment: For notational consistency you need a $||$ around the $F_L$ in your second equation to show that you are taking the magnitude. Although I prefer to just add the vector signs explicitly.

Comment: @enumaris thank you for your correction. Usually I prefer the vector sign too, but, I don’t know why, here on stack the vector sign is just a bit shifted on the right; so here, for aesthetic reasons, I preferred to not put the vector sign.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz Force (in the absence of an Electric Field) is given by $\vec{F}=q(\vec{v}\times \vec{B})=qvB\sin\theta\hat{l}$. Where $\hat{l}$ is the unit vector defined by the right hand rule in the cross product between velocity and magnetic field. As you can see, the Lorentz Force is a proper vector equation that indeed does take into account the direction of the magnetic field (as well as the velocity). The force is directed at 90 degree angles to both the velocity and the magnetic field. The factor of $\sin\theta$ comes in from the fact that it's a cross product.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems as of you have come across **Lorentz Law** first time. I must say that **Lorentz Law** is purely an experimental result. The matter was that when they *switched on* the magnetic field the charged particle which was moving with some velocity $v$ happens to feel acceleration in a direction perpendicular to both it's velocity direction and the direction of the magnetic field with. Now, when they measured the magnitude of the acceleration and multiplied that magnitude with the mass of the charged particle (which is just the force, Newton's Law) the result was always $$ q~v~B~sin\theta$$ where $q$ is magnitude of the charge $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity, B the magnitude of the magnetic field (I'm considering a uniform and time-independent field) and $\theta$ is the angle between the magnetic field and the velocity direction.[You can see a demonstration here.](https://youtu.be/f1xWllhstqk)

In 1773 J.L. Lagrange defined the **cross-product** component-wise and from it the $sin\theta$ form of **cross-product** could be worked out. So, this **cross product** thing became common in dynamics at that time and very customary.

So, combining the experimental results of moving a charged particle in a magnetic field with the mathematics the following things were deduced with extreme surity:

1. Force (acceleration times mass) was orthogonal to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.
2. It has magnitude $F= q~v~B~sin\theta$
3. Therefore, $\mathbf{F} = q(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B})$ .

Hope it helps.

P.S.:- Whatever I have said was just for illustrative purpose, I can't claim what they actually did. The claim about  J.L. Lagrange was taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#History) and the video is from youtube.